# Distribution of integral values of monotonic functions

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value

Consider the family of all integrable monotonically increasing functions $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ (which can be seen as [cumulative distribution functions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cumulative_distribution_function)):

[image]

Of a randomly picked function you know not more than $0 \leq \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx \leq 1$.

For $f(x) = x$ one has $\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx = \frac{1}{2}$.

For each function $f(x)$ with $\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx = F$, the function $f^{-1}(x)$  has $\int_0^1 f^{-1}(x)\ dx = 1 - F$. ($f^{-1}$ is the function you get by reflection at the diagonal.)

So the values of the integrals are somehow symmetrically distributed around $\frac{1}{2}$, probability-wise, so $\frac{1}{2}$ is the expected value.

But **how** are they distributed?

Since $f(x) = x$ leaves more space for variations there will be more functions with $\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx = \frac{1}{2}$ than e.g. with $\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx = 1$, so the probability density of a given value of the integral will not be distributed uniformly around $\frac{1}{2}$.

But **how** exactly? How to calculate this distribution? Is it a Gauss-like curve, possibly?

Or are these questions ill-posed? How then to do better?

---

*[I assume that this question has something to do with [path integrals](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Path_integral_formulation), but I cannot say, what exactly.]*

Comment: You need to specify a distribution, somehow, on the space of such functions $f$. Maybe you intended some sort of uniform distribution, but it is not clear. Without some such assumption no answer can be given.

Comment: I definitely assume some sort of uniform distribution (each function $f$ is equally probable). How should I make this clear?

Comment: The space of such $f$ is a function space, so even existence of a uniform distribution is not obvious, neither what it should mean. What is the reference measure, playing the role of Lebesgue measure on the line?

Comment: In case that you surmise what I mean: Can you give me a hint how to improve my question? (In case you don't: alas! I supposed my question to be well-posed, but you give me the impression that it's not. Now I want to better understand why.)

Comment: I don't really know, but here is a famous paper [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2958401?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) I didn't read (yet). Also there seems to be relevant posts on MathOverflow.  I would start looking into [nonparametric Bayes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=nonparametric+bayes)

Comment: These questions are indeed ill-posed. $(3)$ is impossible because $f^{-1}$ usually isn't even defined.  They don't describe anything definite; and "how to do better" isn't answerable without knowing what you mean by "do better."

Comment: Well, $f^{-1}$ will be defined since it is monotonic increasing ...

Comment: @Kjetil I had read it as assuming $F$ (not $f$) is monotonic.  Reading the question literally shows you are right, but then it makes even less sense.  I think there may be an ambiguity of language: the phrase "Consider the family of all those functions which are basically cumulative distribution functions" can be read to mean "I have just more or less described all cdfs $f$" or it can be read to mean "among the set of such functions consider those which are CDFs."  I begin to suspect the latter interpretation was intended.

Comment: Thank you, Hans-Peter, for the clarifying edits.  Could you explain what you mean by "So the values of the integrals are somehow symmetrically distributed"?  There is no probability measure on the set of distribution functions in evidence here.  You might be interested to note (if you haven't already done so) that $\int_0^1 f^{-1}(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is the expected value of the distribution $f.$